# A custom label field for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I want to use a custom label field in my BlackBerry app.

Answer (score 4):

Some detail about what you are trying to accomplish helps get better answers.  Also an indication of what you have tried on your own is useful to see what level of help you're looking for.

The way to make your own custom version of a field is to subclass the existing class and override the methods to change the behavior in whatever way you want: [LabelField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/LabelField.html)